# How can I export a class from one file to another file in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Imagine I have this class:

```
class Class {
    constructor(arg1, arg2) { arg1 = arg2};
}
```

Should I do this?

```
class Class = exports.Class {
    constructor(arg1, arg2) { arg1 = arg2};
}
```

Or there's another way?

Comment: `class Class = exports.Class {` is a syntax error. You shouldn't write syntax errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `export` syntax, just put `export` before the class:

```
export class Class {
```

(this results in a named export named `Class`)

Or, for a default export:

```
export default class Class {
```

With `module` syntax, assign to `module.exports`, or to a property of `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = class Class {
```

or

```
module.exports.Class = class Class {
```

Comment: Does JavaScript has `extern`, `public` and `private`? So all the members are public?

Comment: Not yet, everything is public, though that may change eventually with `#` syntax. Still, it's easy to make private instance variables with a `WeakMap` indexed by `this`

Comment: how about JSX? Does it have the ability to privatize the class properties?

Comment: JSX is only syntax sugar over JS, so the same thing applies - it's easy to make them private with a `WeakMap`, and a similar implementation may be added to the language later

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this (for other ways, check @Snow answer):

```
class Class {
    constructor(arg1, arg2) { arg1 = arg2};
}

module.exports = Class;
```

Comment: I asked @Snow, I'll ask your too. Are all members of a class public? Isn't that a major security breach?

Comment: Not a security breach. Everyone has access to your javascript if it's running in a browser, even if it's minified, so, the attributes being public doesn't matter for security issues. Typescript has private attribute, you can take advantage of that to make encapsulation, but just for that. Using private attributes doesn't matter for security.